# Problems with RAR -as switch

Tags: windows, rar

I'm having difficulty using the -as switch with rar.exe on windows. When I try to use it while updating an existing archive, or even a completely new one, it attempts to add a couple of records and then throws an error:

> file search errors, cannot synchronize archive

There appears to be little to no documentation of this function at all, and searches for the error message have yielded no help.

The full command I'm trying to use is

> Rar.exe a -as -u -m5 -r -ep1 -esh -os -ms -rr1% -wX:\winrar\temp "X:\misc.rar" H:\*

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem was with those first few records being inaccessible that caused it to crash (H:$RECYLE.BIN and H:Config.Msi apparently). For some reason the -esh option doesn't do anything when trying to archive an entire drive letter. Apparently the extra back slash after the drive letters also don't help either.
The new CMD I used looks like

```
Rar.exe a -u -as -m5 -r -ep1 -esh -os -ms -rr1% -wX:\winrar\temp -x"H:$RECYCLE.BIN" -x"H:Config.Msi" X:\misc.rar H:
```